# replay changes ammended to commit on another branch

Tags: git, branch

I have:

1) created `branch1`

2) committed `commitA1` locally on `branch1`

3) checkout to `branch2` (`commitA1` is applied)

4) Now, on `branch2` I've made some other commits (`commitB1`, `commitB2`, etc.), so it looks like:

```
----commitB2-----
----commitB1-----
----commitA1-----
```

5) Then, I've returned to `branch1` cause I needed to change some things. I've ammended those changes to `commit1A`

6) I realised that I need those recent ammended changes also on `branch2`.

Here, my question is: how to apply those changes to `branch2` in the fastest way? I want to save existing hierarchy, so I want this changes to be applied to `commitA1` on `branch2` (so before `commitB1` and `commitB2`).

I thought that I could `cherry-pick`, but it gives merge conflicts, and after resolving it looks like:

```
----commitA1-----
----commitB2-----
----commitB1-----
----commitA1-----
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `checkout branch2` and `git reset --hard HEAD^` to undo the `cherry-pick`.
2. `git format-patch branch1^..branch1 --stdout > patch` to make a patch that applies changes of the amended `commit1A`.
3. `git rebase -i HEAD~4`, which opens an editor with contents like below:

   ```
   pick ed4dcf2 foo
   pick 6af0cca commitA1
   pick e9cfa08 commitB1
   pick d9856c4 commitB2
   (snip)
   ```
4. Edit the contents like below:

   ```
   e ed4dcf2 foo
   d 6af0cca commitA1
   pick e9cfa08 commitB1
   pick d9856c4 commitB2
   ```

   This means will edit after the commit foo and drop commitA1
5. Save and close the editor, which starts the rebase.
6. The rebase stops after foo. Then, apply the patch by `git apply patch`, delete the patch file, `git add` the changes, and `git commit` them (without --amend).
7. `git rebase --continue` to resume the rebase, which applies commitB1 and commitB2.